# After clicking on submit button I am checking for a condition if it fails how to stop the submission process?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = new Array();
            $('#id_submitbutton').on("click",function(){

                if(languages.length>0){
                    for (var i=0; i<languages.length; i++){
                        arr.push(languages[i].name);
                    } 
                }else{

                $("#id_submitbutton").on("click",function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
              }); 

                }

             $('#id_languages').val(arr);               
            });
```

In this code, On clicking submit button. I am checking for the length of the languages. If that condition gets failed I need to stop the submission process.
How to do that?

I have used the stop propagation. But it's not working out.
Help me out.

Comment: else{ return false; }

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to attach another event handler to the button inside else, just use `event.preventDefault()` in else to stop the default action of the event and pass event to original event handler function

```
var arr = new Array();
$('#id_submitbutton').on("click",function(event){

     if(languages.length>0){
         for (var i=0; i<languages.length; i++){
            arr.push(languages[i].name);
         } 
     }else{
         event.preventDefault();
     }
     $('#id_languages').val(arr);               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault` to stop form submit and

```
var arr = new Array();
$('#id_submitbutton').on("click",function(event){  //<---- pass event as argument

    if(languages.length>0){
        for (var i=0; i<languages.length; i++){
            arr.push(languages[i].name);
        } 
    }else{
        event.preventDefault(); //<--- simply use this to prevent form submission.
    }

    $('#id_languages').val(arr);               
});
```

Comment: Done bro. I don't have enough reputation it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use **event.preventDefault()** to prevent action from occurring.